# Remove Blank Subitems of List

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to remove blank sub-items of a list:

```
l <- list(c(1:3), c(1,"",3))
```

and the output should look like

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
[[2]]
[1] 1 3
```

I've tried the following with no success:

```
l[lapply(l, function(x) x != "")]
```

and the I get the error:

```
Error in l[lapply(l, function(x) x != "")] : 
 invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Seems simple, but I have not found the solution here on SO.

Comment: `lapply(l, function(x) as.numeric(x[x!= ""]))`?

Comment: Please post that as a answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop over the list, and subset each vector to remove blank elements:

```
lapply(l, function(x) as.numeric(x[x!= ""]))
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 3
```

I added `as.numeric` which seemed reasonable.